# python requests drops "data" when use of "header" in request

Tags: python, rest, post, python-requests

I am working on REST API of a site that requires this request type when I want to upload a file:

1. 'Authorization' and multi-part content type in header
2. File as binary string in form (body)
3. File Type in request URL

So I did this code:

```
import requests

url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'

parameters = {
        'format': 'pdf',
        }

headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Authorization' : 'Some authorization code'
        }

data = {'file': open('1.pdf', 'rb')}

r = requests.post(url, params=parameters, headers=headers, data=data)

print(r.text)
```

BUT it seems to requests is dropping data :

```
{
  "args": {
    "format": "pdf"
  },
  "data": "",
  "files": {},
  "form": {},
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Authorization": "Some authorization code",
    "Connection": "close",
    "Content-Length": "30",
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.18.1"
  },
  "json": null,
  "origin": "x.x.x.x",
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post?format=pdf"
}
```

it works **when I remove 'headers' part** in request:

```
r = requests.post(url, params=parameters, data=data)
```

Because response is :

```
{
  "args": {
    "format": "pdf"
  },
  "data": "",
  "files": {},
  "form": {
    "fax_file": "some samplae texts\n"
  },
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Connection": "close",
    "Content-Length": "30",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.18.1"
  },
  "json": null,
  "origin": "x.x.x.x",
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post?format=pdf"
}
```

I have tried prepared request too and result is same.

Comment: What happens if you pass the bytes from reading the file, rather than a file object, in `data`?

Comment: @match is still drops until I removed 'content-type' from headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to post **file data**, so use the `files` option:

```
r = requests.post(url, params=parameters, files=data, headers=headers)
```

You should really not set the `Content-Type` header, however; it is set for you when you use the `files` option. The header in this case  includes the field boundary, to really want the library to take care of this for you:

```
headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Authorization' : 'Some authorization code'
}
```

If you leave the Content-Type header in, you’d have to generate the content body up front to be able to supply the required boundary info to the receiving server.

You could experiment with dropping the `Accept` header too; by default `requests` will add `Accept: */*` if you don't specify that header, signalling that *anything* is acceptable.

When using only the `data` argument, the parameters are encoding to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` form, which doesn't support large file data, and your `Content-Type` header doesn't match the actual POST body content.

See [*Post a Multipart-Encoded File*](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) in the `requests` documentation and [application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data) here on Stack Overflow.

Demo:

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
>>> parameters = {'format': 'pdf'}
>>> headers = {
...   'Accept': 'application/json',
...   'Authorization' : 'Some authorization code',
... }
>>> data = {'file': open('1.pdf', 'rb')}
>>> r = requests.post(url, params=parameters, files=data, headers=headers)
>>> print(r.text)
{
  "args": {
    "format": "pdf"
  },
  "data": "",
  "files": {
    "file": "<file data as base64>"
  },
  "form": {},
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Authorization": "Some authorization code",
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
    "Connection": "close",
    "Content-Length": "374751",
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=d4b84f8bfd464e3f97e3de584d7315fc",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "O2Gw-Id": "03",
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.18.4",
    "X-Gateway": "wap.london.02.net"
  },
  "json": null,
  "origin": "10.120.6.78, 82.132.221.209",
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post?format=pdf"
}
```

Note the `multipart/form-data; boundary=d4b84f8bfd464e3f97e3de584d7315fc` value for the Content-Type header!